# logstash dateparsefailure when parsing begin of summer time

Tags: logstash

In my logstash config file I parse dates as follows:

```
date {
    locale => "de"
    timezone => "Europe/Berlin"
    match => [ "my_datetime_field", "dd.MM.YY HH:mm" ]
    target => "[datetime_field]"
}
```

When I try to parse any of the dates between `29.03.20 02:00` and `29.03.20 02:59` I get _dateparsefailure without any additional information. Dates up to `29.03.20 01:59` are parsed correctly and dates from `29.03.20 03:00` are parsed correctly too.

The results would be

```
"29.03.20 01:59" parsed to "2020-03-29T00:59:00.000Z"
"29.03.20 03:00" parsed to "2020-03-29T01:00:00.000Z"
```

Now I would have expected that the dates between 02:00 and 02:59 are parsed to 01:00 and 01:59 (each on 2020-03-29).

Any ideas why I get _dateparsefailure?

Answer (score 3):

The characters for the year-pattern have to be lowercase. Take a look at the [documentation of the date-filter plugin (current)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html#plugins-filters-date-locale).

So instead of

```
dd.MM.YY HH:mm
```

it should be

```
dd.MM.yy HH:mm
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint. It is working with 'Y' too. I changed it nontheless.